# Self written HMAC function, not working correctly

Tags: c++, hmac

I wrote the following function to generate HMAC-SHA1 referring https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2104, however, the values I generate seem to differ from the values given on https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2202 and from what I've tested on https://www.freeformatter.com/hmac-generator.html.

For example, the function should be generating `de7c9b85b8b78aa6bc8a7a36f70a90701c9db4d9` for text "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog" with key "key", but it generates `d3c446dbd70f5db3693f63f96a5931d49eaa5bab` instead.

Could anyone point out my mistakes?

The function:

```
const int block_size = 64;
const int hash_output_size = 20;
const int ipadVal = 0x36;
const int opadVal = 0x5C;
std::string HMAC::getHMAC(const std::string &text)
{
// check if key length is block_size
// else, append 0x00 till the length of new key is block_size
int key_length = key.length();
std::string newkey = key;
if (key_length < block_size)
{
    int appended_zeros = block_size - key_length;
    // create new string with appended_zeros number of zeros
    std::string zeros = std::string(appended_zeros, '0');
    newkey = key + zeros;
}
if (key_length > block_size)
{
    SHA1 sha1;
    newkey = sha1(key);
}

// calculate hash of newkey XOR ipad and newkey XOR opad
std::string keyXipad = newkey;
std::string keyXopad = newkey;
for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++)
{
    keyXipad[i] ^= ipadVal;
    keyXopad[i] ^= opadVal;
}

// get first hash, hash of keyXipad+text
std::string inner_hash = getSHA1(keyXipad + text);

// get outer hash, hash of keyXopad+inner_hash
std::string outer_hash = getSHA1(keyXopad + inner_hash);

// return outer_hash
return outer_hash;
}
```

edit: In the line

```
std::string zeros = std::string(appended_zeros, '0');
```

'0' should be 0 instead : int instead of char. Thanks to @Igor Tandetnik for that.

Comment: Are you doing this just for education, or do you want to actually use your HMAC function somewhere? Because if it’s the latter, you really should find a library to do it for you. Either way, are you sure the `SHA1` class works correctly?

Comment: Just for education. I've tested the SHA1 with various values against online tools and it is working well. I even set up breakpoints and tested the values and their SHA1 values and all seemed correct. That's why I'm puzzled right now.

Comment: `'0' != 0` ....

Comment: Okay...that was flaw. Thanks for that :D Output still not matching though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok..so a little look around lead me to [HMAC produces wrong results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34522863/hmac-produces-wrong-results). Turns out, I was doing the same mistake of using hex as ascii.

I used a function to convert the inner_hash from hex to ascii and then everything turned out perfect.

The final version of the function:

```
std::string HMAC::getHMAC(const std::string &text)
{
// check if key length is block_size
// else, append 0x00 till the length of new key is block_size
int key_length = key.length();
std::string newkey = key;
if (key_length < block_size)
{
    int appended_zeros = block_size - key_length;
    // create new string with appended_zeros number of zeros
    std::cout << "\nAppending " << appended_zeros << " 0s to key";
    std::string zeros = std::string(appended_zeros, 0);
    newkey = key + zeros;
}
if (key_length > block_size)
{
    SHA1 sha1;
    newkey = sha1(key);
}

// calculate hash of newkey XOR ipad and newkey XOR opad
std::string keyXipad = newkey;
std::string keyXopad = newkey;
for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++)
{
    keyXipad[i] ^= ipadVal;
    keyXopad[i] ^= opadVal;
}

// get first hash, hash of keyXipad+text
std::string toInnerHash = keyXipad + text;
std::string inner_hash = getHash(toInnerHash);

// get outer hash, hash of keyXopad+inner_hash
std::string toOuterHash = keyXopad + hex_to_string(inner_hash);
std::string outer_hash = getHash(toOuterHash);

// return outer_hash
return outer_hash;
}
```

hex_to_string function taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/16125797/3818617